# Asp.net with C #

Tags: asp.net

I want to select the respective department of user when they enter from the database and send users to respective pages

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\csharp\\Drawing\\App_Data\\Drawing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from userstable where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'and Password='"+TextBox2.Text+"'", conn);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!dr.Read())
    {
        Response.Write("User name or password Incorrect");
    }
    else {

          \\I have a column for department in my database how to select it(it has 4 separate departments)
    }
```

---

Comment: I just dont know how to do it ......I have a database which has name password and dept ....when a user enters using his name and p/w i want to sort them to their respective pages depending on the department they work for...I want the else part to be completed so that i can move further

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, so that it will help me to understand your problem and sort it out.

Comment: I have to create a Site where users will Log on.The users might be from different departments.There is one admin.When a user logs in using his user name and password he should be directed form log in page to his department page.I have user names password and their respective departments in Database.SO when a person logs in my code should check which department he is from and send them only to that page

Comment: Fix your question TITLE first... :(

Comment: Why don't you dispose all the `IDisposable` variables? Why don't you use parameters? Why don't you try something first?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
else {

      var department = dr["DepartmentNum"].ToString();
      if(department=="01")
       Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
      else if(department=="04")
        //... etc.
}
```

The above code assumes you have a column in your user table called "DepartmetNum". Also note that doing `select *` is not a good practice. You should explicitly say which columns you inted to select and nothing more.

Most importantly, your code is prone to SQL Injection attacks because you are building your SQL statements by simply concatenating strings. A malicious user can craft a valid query that can for example, drop your entire database.

Instead, write parametrized queries. <s>Google them.</s>

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DeparmentNUm from userstable where Name = @Name and Password = @Password", conn))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",txtBox2.Text);
     //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

```
var deptId = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("department"));
```

(assuming that your department column is called "department").

---

Note, though, there are various other things that should be fixed in your code:

- Don't copy user input into the SQL string. That's error-prone and a security vulnerability ([SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Use *parameterized SQLs* instead.
- `Dispose` objects whose classes implement `IDisposable`. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). In your example, this includes the database connection, the command and the data reader.¹

Here's an example on how to fix these issues:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\csharp\\Drawing\\App_Data\\Drawing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from userstable where Name = @Name and Password = @Password", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write("User name or password Incorrect");
                    return;
                }

                var deptId = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("department"));
                // do something with deptId
             }
         }
     }
}
```

¹ You will get away with not disposing an SqlCommand, since this is essentially a no-op, but not disposing (or closing) an SqlDataReader will block any another operations you want to perform on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following ideas

**Option 1**

- Step 1: Have a page for department something like
  DepartmentDashboard.aspx
- Step 2: In the else part, pass the
  department name or id or whatever value you have to differentiate the
  department in a query string.
- Step 3: Parse the query string value    in the load event of
  DepartmentDashboard.aspx and display the content    accordingly

**Option 2 (more secure way so that the users will not know the department id)**

- Step 1: Have a page for department something like DepartmentDashboard.aspx
- Step 2: In the else part, keep the department name or id or whatever value you have to differentiate the department in the users session. The code looks something like as shown below.

  Session["department_id"] = [pass the department id here];
- Step 3: Retrieve the value from the session variable in the load event of DepartmentDashboard.aspx and display the content accordingly